# Material UI: How do I divide a table into 2 parts?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to divide a table into 2 halves using a vertical line(e.g. blue line in the image) such that there are 2 sections of columns. Each section of column can have multiple columns as follows (Please pardon my terrible drawing skills). How can I achieve this using material ui table?

[image]

Please help me out. Thanks

What I've tried till now(didnt work):

```
const tableHeaders      = this.getTableHeaders()
const tableRows         = this.getTableRows()

return (
    <div className='segment-table-container'>
        <TableContainer>
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell />
                        <TableCell>Field</TableCell>
                        <Divider orientation='vertical' />
                        {tableHeaders}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {tableRows}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Show us what you've tried and what is not working.

Comment: @maazadeeb I tried searching around but couldn't find a decent solution for my problem statement, I did try using material ui's own Divider API, but didnt work. I've attached my code now.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289613/drawing-a-left-border-for-the-whole-border-in-material-ui-tables/64289689#64289689 - it will help you